# Best Drupal GUI for displaying a tiered restaurant menu?

Tags: user-interface, drupal, menu

Our restaurant menus are pretty boring right now and display in plain text format w/ a lot of page scrolling required.  We'd like to break them up into sections and add section thumbnails.  Any ideas on modules or Drupal GUIs we can use to make this the most user-friendly for web visitors?  I've seen some posts on how to create menus with content-types/vocabulary, but I'm more interested in presentation at this point.

Here's an example of the tiered structure we're working with:

```
Main restaurant page
-- Breakfast
---- Eggs
---- Pancakes
---- Sides
---- Skillets
-- Lunch
---- Burgers
---- Sandwiches
---- Desserts
-- Dinner
---- Pasta
---- Soups
---- Desserts
---- Favorites
```

We've tried pages linked to other pages w/ manual coding, but it's messy and not good for usability.  Ideally, we'd love something with consistent navigation, perhaps show/hide DIVs to make sections appear instantaneously, and reusable for our other menus.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Just saw this and may have to check it out: http://openmenu.com/blog/2011/01/openmenu-drupal-module-released/

Comment: MattB:  Do you have any progress with this I am very interested to have a look at the work you have done to date?  We may be able to pull resources to help achieve better results if you like?

Would love to hear from you and how this is going either way.

Comment: Ended up not going the OpenMenu route yet as the available module from them is only for Drupal 7 and we're still on 6.  For now, I'm using a Quicktabs and Colorbox module combination.  The main level items such as Breakfast, Lunch, and Dinner are separate "tabs" which I've styled so that only a visual thumbnail shows.  Once a "tab" is clicked, the associated menu thumbnails then show below with text menus available via Colorbox.  Didn't need to modify any Drupal view template files, but did need to do some CSS work for both Quicktabs and Colorbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is the [Quick Tabs module](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs). You could set up a separate tab for each meal (breakfast, lunch, or dinner).

Comment: Thanks!  This looks like it may be exactly what I'm after.  I wonder if it could support dynamic thumbnails in the tabs that pull from node image fields?

Comment: @MattB You can include Views in your tabs, so it's easy to include just about any kind of content from your site.

Comment: Sorry, meant images in or next to the tab text itself.  So, for example, it'd be: [image 1] Menu 1 | [image 2] | [image 3] Menu 3.  You're right, I just tried Quick Tabs and love how content can be pulled from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks again.  I ended up going this route and the menu looks fabulous.  Way better than text all over the page.  I ended up creating a custom quicktab style to only show a thumbnail image rather than the tab text.